# i am getting compile error here end if without block if?

Tags: excel

```
Dim sCellVal As String

sCellVal = Range("F7").Value
    'gets error end if without block if
    If sCellVal Like "*700*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "800*" Then ws_output = "Rs"
        next_row = Sheets(ws_output).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 1).Value = Range("date").Value
        Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 2).Value = Range("name1").Value
        Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 3).Value = Range("rs_number").Value
        Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 4).Value = Range("amount1").Value
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is an indentation problem. It is hard to tell from your original post, which also lacks indentation, but the error means that it can't figure out what `If` clause the `End If` is referring to. It should look something like what you see below.

Your code contains the `ws_output="Rs"` on the same line as the Then - change that and you should be good.

```
sCellVal = Range("F7").Value 
If sCellVal Like "700" Or _ sCellVal Like "800*" Then 
    ws_output = "Rs" 
    next_row = Sheets(ws_output).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row 
    Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 1).Value = Range("date").Value 
    Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 2).Value = Range("name1").Value 
    Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 3).Value = Range("rs_number").Value 
    Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 4).Value = Range("amount1").Value 
End If
```

EDIT: It would be helpful if you would enter your code in the right format - use the editor "Code" feature and it will come out much better. That way we can see where the problem might lie.